# Is this possible to get the User's highlight colour on OS X using Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want that colour value using Cocoa:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The NSColor for the users Highlight color  will be the control color  **selectedControlColor**

As far as I know you first have to convert the selectedControlColor to a known color space as it is not based on the NSNamedColorSpace.

> NSNamedColorSpace =  Catalog name and color name components
>       The components of this color space are indexes into lists or catalogs of prepared colors. The catalogs of named colors come with
>   lookup tables that are able to generate the correct color on a given
>   device.

---

> Generally, it is recommended that you use calibrated (or generic)
>   color spaces instead of device color spaces. The colors in device
>   color spaces can vary widely from device to device, whereas calibrated
>   color spaces usually result in a reasonably accurate color. Device
>   color spaces, on the other hand, might yield better performance under
>   certain circumstances, so if you know for certain the device that will
>   render or capture the color, use a device color space instead.

---

A code example

```
 NSColor *aColor = [[NSColor selectedControlColor] colorUsingColorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace];
    if (aColor) {
        NSLog(@"   Red %f, Green %f, Blue %f,  Alpha %f,", aColor.redComponent,aColor.greenComponent,aColor.blueComponent,aColor.alphaComponent);
    }
```

see the [Creating and Converting Color Spaces section in the Color Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/UsingColorSpaces.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001807-96846)

Which will give you more idea of how this works and finding how many components a colour has.

Comment: This gives me a light blue that seems to be what appears under "Highlight Color" in System Preferences > General. I'm looking for the Blue/Graphite that appears under "Appearance", which is the color to which e.g. table view cells are highlighted on selection.

Comment: I found it: `selectedMenuItemColor`. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/selectedControlColor

Comment: Thats not it. If you set the system highlight color in `General` preferences to e.g. green, the menu item color will still be blue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the methods on the `NSColor` class to get the user's preferences.

The **[Accessing System Colors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/SystemColors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000790)** section in **[Color Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/DrawColor.html)** states that

> NSColor has a number of methods that return system colors: colors
>   controlled by user preferences. These colors—currently only
>   `selectedControlColor` and `selectedTextBackgroundColor`—should be used by
>   developers who want to create custom controls or subclass existing
>   controls while honoring the user's color preferences.